# Interactive Mobile Device ( Samsung Smart Tv Android)

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv

I am doing an Android app that works like a remote for Samsung Smart TV and I used as base the SamyGo app source, but i have some problems and maybe someone can help me.

The app connects the phone with the TV and after that I use the phone to send data to an app installed on the TV. I am following the Samsung documentation for Interactive Mobile Device, and in this document I read that I have to synchronize the MAC address of the phone with the TV, I can do this without problems.

After I have connected the phone with the TV, I send a request to the TV's server host.

The request has to be `http://tv_ip/connect` on the 55001 port and I obtain the below response:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:85)
  at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
  at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:179)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
  at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
  at de.quist.app.samyGoRemote.Remote$BackgroundThread.run(Remote.java:443)
```

In the first moment I didn't have any problems and everything worked ok, but some days ago I started to have this problem.

Comment: i am trying to make a remote app on android i have samyoGo app source code but i really can't understand it , what i figure out you get the ip address of tv then you make a remote session and use it to send keys to app , am i right ?? could you help me ?what steps should i make to connect to TV and start sending , i don't know you mean by synchronize mac address with tv and how to do it